# .htaccess case sensitive and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
CheckCaseOnly On
CheckSpelling On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^Blog/(.*?)$ /Me/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The problem is, when the URL is like this, it works:

```
localhost/Me/Blog/ExampleUser
```

But it doesn't work when it is like this (notice the 'b' in 'Blog' is in lowercase?):

```
localhost/Me/blog/ExampleUser
```

I'm running it on the new version of XAMPP. It is wierd its not working even though I have the mod_speling.so  on the PHP config.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Use of the **[NC]** flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.

Try **[QSA,L,NC]** instead, so the comparison is made [in a case-insensitive manner](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that rewrite rules ARE case sensitive.  So your Rewrite rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^[Bb]log/(.*?)$ /Me/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and voila you are fixed.

mod_speling.so has NOTHING to do with this.