# changing last part of URL to be lowercase using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, uppercase, lowercase

I want if someone type the url like this

1. http://sim.com/Contact
2. http://sim.com/CONTACT

then it will be redirected to http://sim.com/contact

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess case sensitive and mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579652/htaccess-case-sensitive-and-mod-rewrite)

Comment: i cannot understand please let me know how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

First add this line in `<VirtualHost>` section *OR* at the end of your httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then have this rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*?[A-Z].*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i dont know where this file locate http.conf and i write this line to htaccess it redirected to main website url but i want it will redirected to lower case

Comment: This is the only way to lowercase URIs. You need to contact a server admin to help you out for changing Apache server cofnig.

Comment: hi anubhava server admin said they cannot change apache server because they have shared hosting please let me know is this is helpful to me RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^.+\.html$ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html) [NC]

Comment: See without `RewriteMap` defined in `httpd.conf` you can't use `${lc:$1}`

Comment: but the above code is working on one of my website but that site url is differ with the current in that i was not define RewriteMap

Comment: In that case `RewriteMap` would have been there by default.