# URL consist lower and upper case characters causes 404 error instead of correcting the character case

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I guess this is .htaccess related question rather then php.

Here is my problem, I have several URL that contain both lower and upper case characters.

If by an accident the character is mistyped, then this would cause a 404. My question is, how can I correct the mistyped character to the right case such as `mysite.com/MyFolder/something.html` from `mysite.com/myfolder/something.html`.

I guess this has to be some way of doing this using .htaccess rewrite rules, but I am not particularly a huge pro on this subject.

I have had to place this edit to my question, because I think it was misinterpreted.

So here is the problem, the above mentioned URL is somehow being corrected right within the address bar on one of my competitors website, no matter which letter case you use, as long as it is spelled correctly, the URL it self will jump to the correct case.

So if you spelled something like the following `mysite.com/myfoLDer/something.html` it will automatically correct the URL and give the following `mysite.com/MyFolder/something.html` right in the address bar of the browser on any given URL.

Please help me a little or a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make urls case insensitive in linux server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814419/how-do-i-make-urls-case-insensitive-in-linux-server)

Comment: No it is not actually, my question is substantially different, instead of making URL case sensitive, I need to somehow correct it so that it is matched to the actual virtual directory and correct any mistyped letter to the correct case.

Comment: Please add the contents of your `.htaccess` to the question body

Answer (score 1):

Use `mod_rewrite` for ignoring case handling by using `NC` flag:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [NC]
```

---

[RewriteRule Flags - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc):

> Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.
>
> In the example below, any request for an image file will be proxied to your dedicated image server. The match is case-insensitive, so that .jpg and .JPG files are both acceptable, for example.

Comment: I have just edited my question, please have a look if you have a minute to spare.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [mod_speling and the `CheckCaseOnly` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html#checkcaseonly):

```
CheckCaseOnly On
```

assuming you've got mod_speling loaded.

Comment: No, I don't actually, let me try, so I have to use that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question was already answered here:

[.htaccess case sensitive and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579652/htaccess-case-sensitive-and-mod-rewrite)

> Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.

Comment: this is my current rule RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]