# Redirect to PHP class after HTML form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I'm trying to execute a PHP class after a HTML form submit but my browser display that it couldn't open the specify address.
Here's my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 
  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>

<head>    
    <title>Logins</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='login_form'>
        <form action='<?php echo base_url();?>Login/process' method='post' name='process'>
            <h2>User Login</h2>
            <br />            
            <label for='username'>UsernameTest</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username' size='25' /><br />

            <label for='password'>Password</label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' size='25' /><br />                            

            <input type='Submit' value='Login' />            
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my PHP's class:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        // Load our view to be displayed
        // to the user
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }

        public function process(){
        // Load the model
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        // Validate the user can login
        $result = $this->login_model->validate();
        // Now we verify the result
        if(! $result){
            // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
            $this->index();
        }else{
            // If user did validate, 
            // Send them to members area
            redirect('home');
        }        
    }
}
?>
```

The class is in the Controller folder and the form is in the View folder

Thank's

Comment: Well, obviously, yes. He is using CodeIgniter. Do you have any routes that may overwrite the default route (class/method) ?

Comment: I think you need to use `site_url()` instead of base.

Comment: Hello everybody, I'm currently using Codeigniter and honestly copy/past a code found on internet. But what do you mean about "any routes " that could overwrite the (class/method) ? Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configured your site as something like `http://www.mywebsite.org` in your config file, then the line:

```
<form action='<?php echo base_url();?>Login/process' method='post' name='process'>
```

Will render as:

```
<form action='http://www.mywebsite.orgLogin/process' method='post' name='process'>
```

which is obviously not what you intended because `http://www.mywebsite.orgLogin/process` isn't even a valid URL. To render URLs in CodeIgniter, use `site_url()`:

```
<form action='<?php echo site_url('Login/process');?>' method='post' name='process'>
```

Aside for this, there may be two other problems you might want to check out:

- the `/Login/process` page doesn't exist
- the `/home` page doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

First echo or dump your `base_url()` to see what is there, or use `site_url()` .I usually use `'/'` as `/controller_name/function` and please use 'login' not 'Login'.

Comment: I display the value of site_url() and gave me:
__
localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/login/process
__
Exactly what I want without the uppercase 'L' otherwise, it still doesn't work. But can you tell me why need I to write 'login' and not 'Login' (The both case doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

It works when I write manually the following URL:

```
localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/Login/process
```

But doesn't work using the form redirection.

```
<form action='<?php echo site_url('Login/process/');?>' method='post' name='process'>
```

Thanks

Comment: Include url helper in your controller or in autoload file.

Comment: @I've tried to add 
---
$this->load->helper('url');
---
Nothing change

Comment: Show your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Tpojka 
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all

Comment: @Tpojka 
I'm not really sure about the report between my problem and the .htaccess. Do you think that the problem is about my URL ? Thanks

Comment: If you want to use URL without `index.php` you have to rewrite it with `.htaccess`. Regardless, you can also use apache flag to solve that matter. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579652/htaccess-case-sensitive-and-mod-rewrite#answer-16579927).

Comment: For the moment, it doesn't disturb me if there's index.php into my URL.
But is there a report between my problem and the URL ? thanks

Comment: Not sure but maybe something with machine/OS?

Comment: I'm using Os Maverick and MAMP