# Case sensitivity only by all lowercase or all uppercase?

Tags: php, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, mod-speling

In my CMS I've made a style adaptation in PHP code.

```
<img src="/var/thumbs<?= $next_page_url ?>.JPG" height="50" alt="Next">
```

There are the following phenomenon:

If a file name has both uppercase and lowercase letters (PIC123a.jpg), it does not work. If a file name only uppercase (PIC123.JPG) or only lowercase (pic-test.jpg) it worked.

If I use the entries in the .htaccess it also works with mixed uppercase and lowercase letters.

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
  CheckCaseOnly On
  CheckSpelling On
</IfModule>
```

But I want to know why it will not work without these `.htaccess` entries,  respectively with only uppercase or only lowercase.

PS: The CMS have only the var `$next_page_url`, not `$next_page_item`. I don't want to make too many PHP hacks.

--- EDIT --- More Infos ---

Without the htaccess entry:

If the file extension uppercase AND the file name uppercase (PIC123.JPG) = it works

If the file extension lowercase AND the file name lowercase (pic-test.jpg) = it works

If the file extension lowercase AND the file name has uppercase (PIC123.jpg) = don't work

Comment: [read this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579652/htaccess-case-sensitive-and-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @Martin there is nothing wrong with using the short echo tag `<?=`. Even if short tags are disabled (`<?`), the short echo is still enabled. And it wouldn't mater if there was a space after the `=`. That would make no difference, space or not, as whitespace within php code and around variables, strings, etc is ignored.

Comment: I have [QSA, L, NC] inserted, without success. php short_tag is enabled. There isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you're hitting a url it means you're hitting a server like apache or nginx . php itself is not a server . it just process requests btu those requests are firstly handled by web servers like apache or nginx

The CheckSpelling operative makes Apache perform a more involved effort to find a match e.g. correcting common spelling mistakes

So that is why this chunk of code is used to do the task

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
  CheckCaseOnly On
  CheckSpelling On
</IfModule>
```

Get it? :)

Happy codding!

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_speling.html
What do you want me to say? That is the function too violent for it?

Comment: From my opinion , yes buddy! :)