# Error accessing files with capital letters in Wordpress site with UAM (User Access Manager) plugin

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, user-access-manager

I'm using a plugin to control access of pages and files in a Wordpress website using the plugin UAM (https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/)

I have errors (404) accessing **non locked files** in my WordPress upload folder after activating the “lock files”.
I noticed that the files with error are files with different caps, as the following:
/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Arkhe_-Carta_do_Gestor_-Carta_Gestor_Arkhe.pdf

If the file is all low caps, it works fine, like the example:
/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/carta-prev-crdito-privado_cred.pdf

I think it is some code in the htaccess, but I don’t know what I need to change in it... I tried to study about then, but is too advanced for my knowledge.

The htacess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<FilesMatch '\.(pdf|mp4)'>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\/sites\/[0-9]+\/.* 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}.*$ 
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?uamfiletype=attachment&uamgetfile=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?(((?!uamfiletype).)*)$ /index.php?uamfiletype=attachment&uamgetfile=$1&$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?(.*)$ /index.php?uamgetfile=$1&$2 [QSA,L]
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Somebody could help me? I already tried the plugin support without success.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16579927/9534819)?

Comment: @Matt.G I tried now, but it didn't worked... I don't know why, but with or without the NC, the results are the same.

Comment: have you added the NC to all 4 RewriteRule?

Comment: Yes (and other combinations). But still the same, the small caps only files open without problem, but the mixed ones no. When I delete the .htaccess they all work fine.